# F# use constructors as functions

Tags: constructor, f#, delegates, downcast

I have a use case for treating a constructor for a derived type as a delegate and I can't figure out if it's impossible or I'm just incapable of working it out.

```
type SomeJobEvent(jobId : int, otherThing : string) =
    member this.JobId = jobId
    member this.OtherThing = otherThing

type SomeJobStarted(jobId : int, otherThing : string) =
    inherit SomeJobEvent(jobId, otherThing)

type SomeJobComplete(jobId : int, otherThing : string) =
    inherit SomeJobEvent(jobId, otherThing)

type SomeJobError(jobId : int, otherThing : string) =
    inherit SomeJobEvent(jobId, otherThing)
```

Lets imagine that this is the model, in real life the model happens to be in C# and my code is in F#, but for brevity it's much easier to type out in F#.

And what I want to do is...

```
let raise eventObject = 
    // This is just a helper, the raise event takes obj.
    eventRaiser.Raise(eventObject)

let raise jobId otherThing eventConstructor = 
    // Lets treat the 'event' constructor as a function
    raise(eventConstructor(jobId, otherThing))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 

    // Lets curry this function up so I don't have to pass around 1234
    let raiseEventForJob1234 = raise 1234 "other thing"

    raiseEventForJob1234 SomeJobStarted

    raiseEventForJob1234 SomeJobComplete
```

Now as the constructors passed into the `raiseEventForJob1234` have the same signature and are part of the same inheritance chain, it feels possible. It's just I am not sure how to make it work, it's not even that they all quack, they are actually ducks!

Edit: There is a great answer here from [@tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33518/tomas-petricek), but also a really useful extension from [Piaste in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442637/f-use-constructors-as-functions#comment62389841_37443069) make sure you check out both.

Comment: Not that new at all and I know C# very well. But I don't have any knowledge base around me other than the internet. I know how I could do this in C# using some pretty knarley reflection, but it seems like F# should be able to do it more elegantly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are getting here is called *value restriction* - basically, if you want to use function as generic, it has to be defined as an explicit function.

In your case `raiseEventForJob1234` is generic (it can create and trigger different types of events), but it is defined as a value. Adding an argument solves this:

```
let raiseEventForJob1234 f = raise 1234 "other thing" f

raiseEventForJob1234 SomeJobStarted
raiseEventForJob1234 SomeJobComplete
```

Also note that this only works in F# 4.0 (in Visual Studio 2015). Previous version of F# did not support treating constructors as functions.

Comment: That's amazing! I'll have to read up more on value restriction then. I thought the currying would just handle that for me and the value would be the right function. I've hit this with 'void' parameter functions before, wasn't expecting it here.

Comment: Sub question, as we're here is then. Is there any way I can pass a curried version as an argument without having to `let` define each version with the parameter? I guess not.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars Easiest approach is to use a "currifier" function. Many libraries provide them, or you can write it yourself if it's a one-off: `let curry2 f = fun a -> fun b -> f(a, b)`. LMK if I understood you correctly.

Comment: This is amazing stuff. I'll link this in the question.